# Why does the enqueued owl carousel work with the NewsMag Pro theme version, and not with the default WordPress Installation?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to write and submit a new WordPress plugin, and I have the goals of needing the plugin to show a "snippet" of our main site newyorkbusinessreview.com including our books selection and also some of our published journal articles which are featured in carousel sliders.  I checked the HTML code using Firefox and Shift-Control-C in the originalnewyorkbusinessreview.com site, and the carousel sliders are based on the owl carousel, but probably not the latest version.  (See owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/demos.html for the demonstration page for the  owlcarousel2 latest documentation for the latest version of the Owl Carousel Slider.)

Consulting with the Site Editor, it is very important that our plugin "fits very nicely" wherever it is posted.  However, the *same HTML code* renders one way on one page and another way on the next, with the theme page working of course fine and a fresh install of WordPress 4.7.5 (just downloaded from the WordPress site) does not.  I only added in one plugin on the fresh WordPress 4.7.5 (being the amr-shortcode-any-widget, a very nice plugin that allows widgets to be directly placed on a page) to test it.

I was advised by WordPress plugin review to use wp_enqueue_style and so forth to enqueue everything properly.  I found the part of the main theme that did this (it was in one file, enqueue.php) and I updated it as posted below.

Because there is a lot of code here already, and those skilled in WordPress can access the relevant files knowing the main web url, for "brevity" I have not put here additional code.  But if requested, of course I can of course update it.  Also within Firefox Shift-Control-C can be used to view specific elements at each web-site code directly.

So why does it work with the NewsMag Pro theme version, and not with the default WordPress Installation?

Any ideas?

#### Test Page - Fresh Install Plugin Output That Does Not Work (See:  http://support.issues.owl.newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/test-page/ )

[Image Showing Carousel Not Working (click link to view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fTdV.jpg)

```html
<div id="newsmag_widget_posts_carousel-5" class="widget newsmag_builder">  <div class="clearfix"></div>
 <div class="col-md-12 newsmag-posts-carousel" id="newsmag-color-coded-5102">
  <h2>
       <span>Books, Magazines, and Journals</span>
      </h2>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="newsmag-carousel-navigation hidden-xs text-right">
    <ul class="newsmag-carousel-arrows clearfix">
     <li>
      <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/category/books-magazines-and-journals/">VIEW ALL</a>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#" class="newsmag-owl-prev fa fa-angle-left"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="newsmag-owl-next fa fa-angle-right"></a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
      <div class="owlCarousel owl-carousel owl-theme col-md-12" data-slider-id="4193" id="owlCarousel-4193" data-slider-items="4" data-slider-speed="400" data-slider-auto-play="true" data-slider-navigation="false">
         <div class="item">
      <div class="newsmag-image">
              <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/24/the-seven-secrets-of-influence-and-a-swift-kick-in-the-cants-by-elaina-zuker/">
        <img src="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/SevenSecretsofInfluenceAndASwiftKickintheCants-350x260.jpg" class="attachment-newsmag-post-horizontal size-newsmag-post-horizontal wp-post-image" alt="" width="350" height="260">       </a>
              <span class="newsmag-post-box-category ">
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/category/books-magazines-and-journals/">
        Books, Magazines, and Journals       </a>
      </span>
      </div>

      <h3>
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/24/the-seven-secrets-of-influence-and-a-swift-kick-in-the-cants-by-elaina-zuker/">The Seven Secrets of Influence…</a>
      </h3>

      <div class="meta">
       <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> April 24, 2017       <a class="newsmag-comments-link" href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/24/the-seven-secrets-of-influence-and-a-swift-kick-in-the-cants-by-elaina-zuker//#comments"><span class=" fa fa-comment-o"></span> 0</a>             </div>
     </div>
         <div class="item">
      <div class="newsmag-image">
              <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/hbr-essentials-and-two-complementary-books/">
        <img src="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/HBR_Three_Book_Set-350x260.jpg" class="attachment-newsmag-post-horizontal size-newsmag-post-horizontal wp-post-image" alt="" width="350" height="260">       </a>
              <span class="newsmag-post-box-category ">
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/category/books-magazines-and-journals/">
        Books, Magazines, and Journals       </a>
      </span>
      </div>

      <h3>
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/hbr-essentials-and-two-complementary-books/">HBR Essentials and Two Complementary…</a>
      </h3>

      <div class="meta">
       <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> April 23, 2017       <a class="newsmag-comments-link" href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/hbr-essentials-and-two-complementary-books//#comments"><span class=" fa fa-comment-o"></span> 0</a>             </div>
     </div>
         <div class="item">
      <div class="newsmag-image">
              <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/harvard-business-review-magazine/">
        <img src="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/61ctTvIvJL1-e1492968160410-350x218.jpg" class="attachment-newsmag-post-horizontal size-newsmag-post-horizontal wp-post-image" alt="" width="350" height="218">       </a>
              <span class="newsmag-post-box-category ">
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/category/books-magazines-and-journals/">
        Books, Magazines, and Journals       </a>
      </span>
      </div>

      <h3>
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/harvard-business-review-magazine/">Harvard Business Review Magazine</a>
      </h3>

      <div class="meta">
       <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> April 23, 2017       <a class="newsmag-comments-link" href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/harvard-business-review-magazine//#comments"><span class=" fa fa-comment-o"></span> 0</a>             </div>
     </div>
         <div class="item">
      <div class="newsmag-image">
              <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/hbrs-10-must-reads/">
        <img src="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/HBR10MostReads1-350x260.jpg" class="attachment-newsmag-post-horizontal size-newsmag-post-horizontal wp-post-image" alt="" width="350" height="260">       </a>
              <span class="newsmag-post-box-category ">
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/category/books-magazines-and-journals/">
        Books, Magazines, and Journals       </a>
      </span>
      </div>

      <h3>
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/hbrs-10-must-reads/">HBR’s 10 Must Reads</a>
      </h3>

      <div class="meta">
       <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> April 23, 2017       <a class="newsmag-comments-link" href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/hbrs-10-must-reads//#comments"><span class=" fa fa-comment-o"></span> 0</a>             </div>
     </div>
         <div class="item">
      <div class="newsmag-image">
              <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/19/aiming-at-amazon-the-new-business-of-self-publishing-or-how-to-publish-your-books-with-print-on-demand-and-online-book-marketing-on-amazon-com-by-aaron-shepard-2007-01-01/">
        <img src="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/AimingAtAmazon-350x248.jpg" class="attachment-newsmag-post-horizontal size-newsmag-post-horizontal wp-post-image" alt="" width="350" height="248">       </a>
              <span class="newsmag-post-box-category ">
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/category/books-magazines-and-journals/">
        Books, Magazines, and Journals       </a>
      </span>
      </div>

      <h3>
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/19/aiming-at-amazon-the-new-business-of-self-publishing-or-how-to-publish-your-books-with-print-on-demand-and-online-book-marketing-on-amazon-com-by-aaron-shepard-2007-01-01/">Aiming at Amazon: The NEW…</a>
      </h3>

      <div class="meta">
       <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> April 19, 2017       <a class="newsmag-comments-link" href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/19/aiming-at-amazon-the-new-business-of-self-publishing-or-how-to-publish-your-books-with-print-on-demand-and-online-book-marketing-on-amazon-com-by-aaron-shepard-2007-01-01//#comments"><span class=" fa fa-comment-o"></span> 0</a>             </div>
     </div>
         <div class="item">
      <div class="newsmag-image">
              <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/06/latest-business-books/">
        <img src="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/BusinessBooksForSale-350x260.jpg" class="attachment-newsmag-post-horizontal size-newsmag-post-horizontal wp-post-image" alt="" width="350" height="260">       </a>
              <span class="newsmag-post-box-category ">
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/category/books-magazines-and-journals/">
        Books, Magazines, and Journals       </a>
      </span>
      </div>

      <h3>
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/06/latest-business-books/">Latest Business Books</a>
      </h3>

      <div class="meta">
       <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> April 6, 2017       <a class="newsmag-comments-link" href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/06/latest-business-books//#comments"><span class=" fa fa-comment-o"></span> 0</a>             </div>
     </div>
       </div>
  </div><!--/.row-->
 </div>

</div>
```

#### My Modified Equenes.php -- Added Header (See: carousel_edit_url_for_newspro/enqueues.php in the themes directory)

```html
<?php

/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles in the frontend.
 */
function corrected_newsmag_scripts() {
 $corrected_newsmag = wp_get_theme();

 /**
  * Load Google Fonts
  */
  /*
 wp_enqueue_style( 'newsmag-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900|Poppins:400,500,600,700', array(), $newsmag['Version'], 'all' );
   */
 wp_enqueue_style( 'CEU_newsmag-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900|Poppins:400,500,600,700', array(), false, 'all' );

 wp_enqueue_style( 'CEU_font-awesome-style', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/fontawesome//font-awesome.min.css' );

 /**
  * Load the bootstrap framework
  */
 wp_enqueue_style( 'CEU_bootstrap-style', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'CEU_bootstrap-theme-style', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.min.css' );
/*
 wp_enqueue_script( 'newsmag-bootstrap', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), $newsmag['Version'], true );
*/
 wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_newsmag-bootstrap', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );

 /**
  * Load offscreen helper
  */
  /*
 wp_enqueue_script( 'newsmag-offscreen', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/offscreen/offscreen.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), $newsmag['Version'], true );
  */
 wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_newsmag-offscreen', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/offscreen/offscreen.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false , true );

  
 /**
  * Load the Sticky library
  */
  /*
 wp_enqueue_script( 'newsmag-sticky', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/sticky/jquery.sticky.js', array( 'jquery' ), $newsmag['Version'], true );
  */
 wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_newsmag-sticky', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/sticky/jquery.sticky.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );

  
 /**
  * Theme styling
  */

 wp_enqueue_style( 'CEU_newsmag-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
/* 
wp_enqueue_style( 'newsmag-stylesheet', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/css/style.css', array(), $newsmag['Version'] );
*/
        wp_enqueue_style( 'CEU_newsmag-stylesheet', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/css/style.css', array(), false );
  
 /**
  * Load menu script & skip-link-focus-fix
  */

 wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_newsmag-navigation', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/js/navigation.js', array(), $newsmag['Version'], true );
/*  Added CEU_ prefix and also set version to default (false)
 wp_enqueue_script( 'newsmag-skip-link-focus-fix', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), $newsmag['Version'], true );
*/
 wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_newsmag-skip-link-focus-fix', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), false, true );

  
 /**
  * Adsense loader
  */
/* Old version, updated version and CEU_ prefix
 wp_enqueue_script( 'newsmag-adsense-loader', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/adsenseloader/jquery.adsenseloader.js', array('jquery'), $newsmag['Version'], true );
*/

 wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_newsmag-adsense-loader', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/adsenseloader/jquery.adsenseloader.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
  
 /**
  *Load the theme's core Javascript
  */

 wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_machothemes-object', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/machothemes/machothemes.min.js', array(), $newsmag['Version'], true );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_newsmag-functions', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/js/functions.js', array('jquery'), $newsmag['Version'], true );
wp_localize_script( 'CEU_newsmag-functions', 'WPUrls', array(
  'siteurl' => get_option( 'siteurl' ),
  'theme'   => get_template_directory_uri(),
  'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
 ) );

 if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_comment-reply' );
 }

  
 /**
  * OwlCarousel Library
  */
  /*
 wp_enqueue_script( 'owlCarousel-js', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), $corrected_newsmag['Version'], true );
  */
    wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_owlCarousel-js', 
     plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'CEU_owlCarousel-main-css', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'CEU_owlCarousel-theme-css', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.theme.default.css' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'corrected_newsmag_scripts' );

/**
 * Load admin fonts
 */
/*
function corrected_newsmag_admin_scripts() {
 $newsmag = wp_get_theme();
 wp_enqueue_style( 'newsmag-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900|Poppins:400,500,600,700', array(), $newsmag['Version'], 'all' );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'corrected_newsmag_admin_scripts' );
*/

/**
 * Load editor styles
 */
/*
function corrected_newsmag_add_editor_styles() {
 add_editor_style( 'inc/assets/css/custom-editor-style.css' );
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'corrected_newsmag_add_editor_styles' );
*/
```

#### Original Page with the Newsmag Pro Theme That Works (See: http://support.issues.owl.newyorkbusinessreview.com/ )

[Image Showing Carousel Working With NewsMag Pro Theme (click link to view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFfH0.png)

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="newsmag-carousel-navigation hidden-xs text-right">
    <ul class="newsmag-carousel-arrows clearfix">
     <li>
      <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/category/books-magazines-and-journals/">VIEW ALL</a>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#" class="newsmag-owl-prev fa fa-angle-left"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="newsmag-owl-next fa fa-angle-right"></a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
      <div class="owlCarousel owl-carousel owl-theme col-md-12 owl-loaded owl-drag" data-slider-id="4193" id="owlCarousel-4193" data-slider-items="4" data-slider-speed="400" data-slider-auto-play="true" data-slider-navigation="false">
         
         
         
         
         
         
       <div class="owl-stage-outer"><div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(-580px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0.25s ease 0s; width: 1740px;"><div class="owl-item" style="width: 270px; margin-right: 20px;"><div class="item">
      <div class="newsmag-image">
              <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/24/the-seven-secrets-of-influence-and-a-swift-kick-in-the-cants-by-elaina-zuker/">
        <img src="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/SevenSecretsofInfluenceAndASwiftKickintheCants-350x260.jpg" class="attachment-newsmag-post-horizontal size-newsmag-post-horizontal wp-post-image" alt="" width="350" height="260">       </a>
              <span class="newsmag-post-box-category ">
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/category/books-magazines-and-journals/">
        Books, Magazines, and Journals       </a>
      </span>
      </div>

      <h3>
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/24/the-seven-secrets-of-influence-and-a-swift-kick-in-the-cants-by-elaina-zuker/">The Seven Secrets of Influence…</a>
      </h3>

      <div class="meta">
       <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> April 24, 2017       <a class="newsmag-comments-link" href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/24/the-seven-secrets-of-influence-and-a-swift-kick-in-the-cants-by-elaina-zuker//#comments"><span class=" fa fa-comment-o"></span> 0</a>             </div>
     </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 270px; margin-right: 20px;"><div class="item">
      <div class="newsmag-image">
              <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/hbr-essentials-and-two-complementary-books/">
        <img src="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/HBR_Three_Book_Set-350x260.jpg" class="attachment-newsmag-post-horizontal size-newsmag-post-horizontal wp-post-image" alt="" width="350" height="260">       </a>
              <span class="newsmag-post-box-category ">
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/category/books-magazines-and-journals/">
        Books, Magazines, and Journals       </a>
      </span>
      </div>

      <h3>
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/hbr-essentials-and-two-complementary-books/">HBR Essentials and Two Complementary…</a>
      </h3>

      <div class="meta">
       <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> April 23, 2017       <a class="newsmag-comments-link" href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/hbr-essentials-and-two-complementary-books//#comments"><span class=" fa fa-comment-o"></span> 0</a>             </div>
     </div></div><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 270px; margin-right: 20px;"><div class="item">
      <div class="newsmag-image">
              <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/harvard-business-review-magazine/">
        <img src="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/61ctTvIvJL1-e1492968160410-350x218.jpg" class="attachment-newsmag-post-horizontal size-newsmag-post-horizontal wp-post-image" alt="" width="350" height="218">       </a>
              <span class="newsmag-post-box-category ">
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/category/books-magazines-and-journals/">
        Books, Magazines, and Journals       </a>
      </span>
      </div>

      <h3>
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/harvard-business-review-magazine/">Harvard Business Review Magazine</a>
      </h3>

      <div class="meta">
       <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> April 23, 2017       <a class="newsmag-comments-link" href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/harvard-business-review-magazine//#comments"><span class=" fa fa-comment-o"></span> 0</a>             </div>
     </div></div><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 270px; margin-right: 20px;"><div class="item">
      <div class="newsmag-image">
              <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/hbrs-10-must-reads/">
        <img src="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/HBR10MostReads1-350x260.jpg" class="attachment-newsmag-post-horizontal size-newsmag-post-horizontal wp-post-image" alt="" width="350" height="260">       </a>
              <span class="newsmag-post-box-category ">
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/category/books-magazines-and-journals/">
        Books, Magazines, and Journals       </a>
      </span>
      </div>

      <h3>
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/hbrs-10-must-reads/">HBR’s 10 Must Reads</a>
      </h3>

      <div class="meta">
       <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> April 23, 2017       <a class="newsmag-comments-link" href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/23/hbrs-10-must-reads//#comments"><span class=" fa fa-comment-o"></span> 0</a>             </div>
     </div></div><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 270px; margin-right: 20px;"><div class="item">
      <div class="newsmag-image">
              <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/19/aiming-at-amazon-the-new-business-of-self-publishing-or-how-to-publish-your-books-with-print-on-demand-and-online-book-marketing-on-amazon-com-by-aaron-shepard-2007-01-01/">
        <img src="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/AimingAtAmazon-350x248.jpg" class="attachment-newsmag-post-horizontal size-newsmag-post-horizontal wp-post-image" alt="" width="350" height="248">       </a>
              <span class="newsmag-post-box-category ">
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/category/books-magazines-and-journals/">
        Books, Magazines, and Journals       </a>
      </span>
      </div>

      <h3>
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/19/aiming-at-amazon-the-new-business-of-self-publishing-or-how-to-publish-your-books-with-print-on-demand-and-online-book-marketing-on-amazon-com-by-aaron-shepard-2007-01-01/">Aiming at Amazon: The NEW…</a>
      </h3>

      <div class="meta">
       <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> April 19, 2017       <a class="newsmag-comments-link" href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/19/aiming-at-amazon-the-new-business-of-self-publishing-or-how-to-publish-your-books-with-print-on-demand-and-online-book-marketing-on-amazon-com-by-aaron-shepard-2007-01-01//#comments"><span class=" fa fa-comment-o"></span> 0</a>             </div>
     </div></div><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 270px; margin-right: 20px;"><div class="item">
      <div class="newsmag-image">
              <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/06/latest-business-books/">
        <img src="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/BusinessBooksForSale-350x260.jpg" class="attachment-newsmag-post-horizontal size-newsmag-post-horizontal wp-post-image" alt="" width="350" height="260">       </a>
              <span class="newsmag-post-box-category ">
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/category/books-magazines-and-journals/">
        Books, Magazines, and Journals       </a>
      </span>
      </div>

      <h3>
       <a href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/06/latest-business-books/">Latest Business Books</a>
      </h3>

      <div class="meta">
       <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> April 6, 2017       <a class="newsmag-comments-link" href="http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/2017/04/06/latest-business-books//#comments"><span class=" fa fa-comment-o"></span> 0</a>             </div>
     </div></div></div></div><div class="owl-nav disabled"><div class="owl-prev">prev</div><div class="owl-next">next</div></div><div class="owl-dots disabled"></div></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reasons it was not working were:
1)  The enqueue.php file did not properly load the content - plugin_dir_path( **FILE** ) was not correct.
2)  There was a conflict with the style sheets of the main theme and the style sheets of other themes.  Hence the CSS files needed to be updated.
3)  A custom token needed to be put at the beginning: CEU_newsmag-bootstrap for example.  That was in the existing code, but it was an earlier reason why the plugin did not work as intended.

Please submit questions to stephenelliott@newyorkbusinessreview.com

The plugin in the default Twenty-Seventeen Theme (with the additional WordPress plugin "***amr shortcode any widget***" used to place the widget on the page) can be seen at http://support.issues.owl.newyorkbusinessreview.com/ninja/test/

The corrected version of enqueue.php is below (with all the enqueue fixes):

```html
<?php

/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles in the frontend.
 */
function corrected_newsmag_scripts() {
 $corrected_newsmag = wp_get_theme();

 /**
  * Load Google Fonts
  */
  /*
 wp_enqueue_style( 'newsmag-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900|Poppins:400,500,600,700', array(), $newsmag['Version'], 'all' );
   */
 wp_enqueue_style( 'CEU_newsmag-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900|Poppins:400,500,600,700', array(), false, 'all' );

 wp_enqueue_style( 'CEU_font-awesome-style', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/fontawesome//font-awesome.min.css' );

 /**
  * Load the bootstrap framework
  */
 wp_enqueue_style( 'CEU_bootstrap-style', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'CEU_bootstrap-theme-style', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.min.css' );
/*
 wp_enqueue_script( 'newsmag-bootstrap', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), $newsmag['Version'], true );
*/
 wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_newsmag-bootstrap', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );

 /**
  * Load offscreen helper
  */
  /*
 wp_enqueue_script( 'newsmag-offscreen', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/offscreen/offscreen.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), $newsmag['Version'], true );
  */
 wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_newsmag-offscreen', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/offscreen/offscreen.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false , true );


 /**
  * Load the Sticky library
  */
  /*
 wp_enqueue_script( 'newsmag-sticky', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/sticky/jquery.sticky.js', array( 'jquery' ), $newsmag['Version'], true );
  */
 wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_newsmag-sticky', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/sticky/jquery.sticky.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );


 /**
  * Theme styling
  */

 wp_enqueue_style( 'CEU_newsmag-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
/*
wp_enqueue_style( 'newsmag-stylesheet', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/css/style.css', array(), $newsmag['Version'] );
*/
        wp_enqueue_style( 'CEU_newsmag-stylesheet', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/css/style.css', array(), false );

 /**
  * Load menu script & skip-link-focus-fix
  */

 wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_newsmag-navigation', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/js/navigation.js', array(), $newsmag['Version'], true );
/*  Added CEU_ prefix and also set version to default (false)
 wp_enqueue_script( 'newsmag-skip-link-focus-fix', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), $newsmag['Version'], true );
*/
 wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_newsmag-skip-link-focus-fix', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), false, true );


 /**
  * Adsense loader
  */
/* Old version, updated version and CEU_ prefix
 wp_enqueue_script( 'newsmag-adsense-loader', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/adsenseloader/jquery.adsenseloader.js', array('jquery'), $newsmag['Version'], true );
*/

 wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_newsmag-adsense-loader', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/adsenseloader/jquery.adsenseloader.js', array('jquery'), false, true );

 /**
  *Load the theme's core Javascript
  */

 wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_machothemes-object', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/machothemes/machothemes.min.js', array(), $newsmag['Version'], true );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_newsmag-functions', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/js/functions.js', array('jquery'), $newsmag['Version'], true );
wp_localize_script( 'CEU_newsmag-functions', 'WPUrls', array(
  'siteurl' => get_option( 'siteurl' ),
  'theme'   => get_template_directory_uri(),
  'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
 ) );

 if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_comment-reply' );
 }


 /**
  * OwlCarousel Library
  */
  /*
 wp_enqueue_script( 'owlCarousel-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), $corrected_newsmag['Version'], true );
  */
    wp_enqueue_script( 'CEU_owlCarousel-js',
     plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'CEU_owlCarousel-main-css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'CEU_owlCarousel-theme-css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/assets/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.theme.default.css' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'corrected_newsmag_scripts' );

/**
 * Load admin fonts
 */
/*
function corrected_newsmag_admin_scripts() {
 $newsmag = wp_get_theme();
 wp_enqueue_style( 'newsmag-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900|Poppins:400,500,600,700', array(), $newsmag['Version'], 'all' );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'corrected_newsmag_admin_scripts' );
*/

/**
 * Load editor styles
 */
/*
function corrected_newsmag_add_editor_styles() {
 add_editor_style( 'inc/assets/css/custom-editor-style.css' );
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'corrected_newsmag_add_editor_styles' );
*/
```

The CSS files that needed modification (according to the developer we hired at Code Ninjas) were:

> Files with changes: – assets/sass/elements/lists.scss –
>   assets/sass/site/secondary/_widget-recent-posts.scss –
>   assets/css/style.css

These can be found in the standard plugins directory on the demonstration website referenced earlier.  If there are questions feel free to email me at stephenelliott@newyorkbusinessreview.com (which is fast - as I receive an alert about your message - and also a little more flexible in including reference links an pictures currently) or else go to the contact page on http://www.newyorkbusinessreview.com and leave a message there on the contact form page - see the menu link on the bottom of the home page of the site.